# How to set a PHP variable via URL?

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to cause a variable `$btn1Pressed` to be set via a URL load. For example, loading `http://mywebsite.com/myphp.php?btn1Pressed=1` would set the variable to `1`. The below test code doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
<?php
    if ($btn1Pressed == 1) {
        echo 'Button One Pressed'; 
    }

    else{
        echo 'Button Two Pressed'; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Before the vampires arrive...*

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['btn1Pressed']) && $_GET['btn1Pressed'] == 1) {
        echo 'Button One Pressed'; 
    }

    else{
        echo 'Button Two Pressed'; 
    }
?>
```

Anything in the query string will be in PHP's [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array. To see the entire array you can `print_r($_GET);` in your PHP code. In the example I am also testing to make sure the variable has been set, for safeties sake. You should never accept user input without sanitizing, which I have not done here.

You can also set a variable with the array item:

```
$btn1Pressed = $_GET['btn1Pressed'];
```

Comment: Vwahahaha. I was here to suck the easy rep without explaining anything.. but you beat me to it and gave a very good explanation. Thus... I must upvote you instead. =P

Comment: So I tried this method then ran my .php?btn1Pressed=1 but it's still not echoing Button One Pressed?

Comment: Are you running it on a webserver @MattHutch?

Comment: And the code is in server1.php? If so, add error reporting to the top of your page right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Added this line, no changes?

Comment: There must be something else going on. Create a page with just the following in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and load that page into your browser. Let's make sure PHP is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107767/discussion-between-matt-hutch-and-jay-blanchard).

Answer (score 0):

You can try use GET method:

```
if ($_GET['btn1Pressed'] == 1) {
    echo 'Button One Pressed';
}
else{
    echo 'Button Two Pressed'; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$btn_pressed = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'btn1Pressed',  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if ($btn_pressed == 1) {
    echo 'Button One Pressed';
} else {
echo 'anything';
}
?>
```